Firebase In-App Messaging data retrieval in Flutter App
I am integrating firebase in-app messaging to my flutter application. It works fine but there is just one issue I have. When I am trying to compose a campaign with a custom data, I don't know how to retrieve data within my flutter app.
I already searched the documentation of in-app messaging in firebase but I don't see anything how to retrieve it.
